# Unable to load Compute engine from GCP console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I cannot load 'Compute Engine' console. It shows a loading sign endlessly. 
I already checked my IAM and it shows that I have a full control over 'Compute Engine' (I am assigned as a Compute Engine Manager, I think it is not likely related to access control issue).

I tried clearing out caches but it didn't work (I use Chrome).

Below is a screenshot when I tried to load 'Compute Engine'.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tufzk.jpg)

What's wrong?

Comment: Do other menus look good? I suspect your network environment. It is also a good idea to change the language to English.

Comment: I experienced the same thing yesterday evening. This lasted for hours and eventually recovered. Everything using the CLI was normal, just the console GUI had issues.

Comment: 'Big Query' doesn't work either. Strange thing is that when I load 'Big Query' it appears to be normal except that I cannot access datasets. I have a full control over 'Big Query' when I use an old version UI. I think the CLI works OK.

Comment: I deleted my chrome and reinstalled it. And... it worked! (I don't know why this happened... though)